# Why is the environment ignored by the httptest client?

Tags: go, proxy

I have this unit test for a proxy i'm writing. I cannot for the life of me see why the environment get ignored and my test make a direct access to the target server, `acap`.

```
func TestHandleHTTPS(t *testing.T) {
    successfulCalls := 0
    proxyPassed := 0

    acap := httptest.NewTLSServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        successfulCalls++
    }))
    defer acap.Close()

    testproxy := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        proxyPassed++
    }))
    defer testproxy.Close()
    os.Setenv("https_proxy", testproxy.URL)
    defer os.Setenv("https_proxy", "")

    client := acap.Client()
    tmp := client.Transport.(*http.Transport)
    tmp.Proxy = http.ProxyFromEnvironment // <--- This should make client use env vars!                                                                      

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", acap.URL, nil)
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Unable to create request: %s", err.Error())
    }

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Something is wrong with the test: %s", err.Error())
        return
    }

    if resp.StatusCode != 200 {
        t.Errorf("Unexpected status code: %d", resp.StatusCode)
        body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        t.Errorf("Body: %s", string(body))
    }

    if successfulCalls == 0 {
        t.Errorf("No successful call over HTTPS occurred")
    }

    if proxyPassed == 0 {
        t.Errorf("Proxy got ignored")
    }
}
```

The only failure i get is `Proxy got ignored`. I use Go v1.10, everything compiles.

Edit 1:
I do the `tmp.Proxy` dance because the client already have certificates and stuff configured in the `Transport`. I don't want to mess that up by replacing the entire `Transport` struct

Comment: localhost will never use a proxy by default.

Comment: What's my options then?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test here? You don't need to verify that `ProxyFromEnvironment` works, it's already well tested. If you want to verify that your proxy handler works, you need to use your own `Transport.Proxy` func.

Comment: I'm trying to test my own proxy handler. I'll try to write my own proxy function and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at [doc for ProxyFromEnvironment](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ProxyFromEnvironment) you will find there a special case:

> As a special case, if req.URL.Host is "localhost" (with or without a port number), then a nil URL and nil error will be returned.

That means that no proxy will be used. I would suggest you to use [ProxyURL](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ProxyURL) instead

```
proxyURL, _ := url.Parse(testproxy.URL)
tmp.Proxy = http.ProxyURL(proxyURL)
```

It will take into account your Proxy, but won't work, because you are trying to make an https call throw http proxy...

Comment: Are you suggesting something that you confess will not work or am I missing something?

Comment: @PatrikIselind: no, he's showing you haw to create a static proxy function -- it's your proxy as shown here that will not work.

Comment: @PatrikIselind you should create HTTPS listening proxy or you will end up with error: `http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client`. But approach I have suggested is working and will work fine if you will use HTTPS proxy instance